# How to associate .scss files with CSS intellisense in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'd like to be able to use IntelliSense in .scss files for speed, but I can't see a way of associating the file type.

I've tried using Mindscape Web Workbench, and found the functionality didn't meet my needs.

After a bit of research I found that you could build file extension associations in Tools>Options>Text editor>File extension, but none of the options in the Editor DDL seemed applicable for CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012, you can do the following:

Go to Tools > Options > Text editor > File Extension

Enter scss in the Extension box.

Select CSS Source Editor from the Editor box.

For Visual Studio 2010, CSS Source Editor doesn't appear to be an option. This extension appears to do what you ask for: [ScssInCss](http://andrewblogs.com/css-syntax-highlighting-for-scss/).